# T-SQL grouped sum, based on help table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, case

I have a table with a grouping column and a numeric column that I want to summarize. My table looks like this:

```
  Person   Object    Count  
 -------- --------- ------- 
  John     apples        1  
  John     pears         6  
  John     ferrari      10  
  Mike     porsche       3  
  Mike     ferrari       1
```

I want to create a table that returns one row per person, and returns several columns containing a grouping of the objects. In this example, apples and pears are both fruits and ferraris and porsches are both cars. My result table would look like this:

```
  Person   Fruits   Cars  
 -------- -------- ------ 
  John          7     10  
  Mike          0      4
```

I have a help table that assigns every object to a group. The number of groups is set in stone, but I might add more objects in each group. This is why I created this help table, so that when there are new objects featuring in my data, I can simply add a row. For example, I might later add plums (also a fruit) or toyotas (also a car), but I will never add something that is not either a car or a fruit.

```
  Object    Group   
 --------- -------- 
  apples    fruits  
  pears     fruits  
  ferrari   cars    
  porsche   cars
```

My solution is the following query:

```
SELECT
  Person,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Object IN (SELECT Object FROM help_table WHERE Group = 'fruits') THEN Count END) AS Fruits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Object IN (SELECT Object FROM help_table WHERE Group = 'cars') THEN Count END) AS Cars
FROM start_table
GROUP BY Person
```

It returns the following error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

I'm looking for other solutions to reach the desired result. It'd be easy to specify in the query which objects belong to each group, but I'd really prefer adding new objects to a table, and not having to hard-code them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for a small, finite set of groups

```
SELECT
  Person,
  COUNT(hf.Object),
  COUNT(hc.Object)
FROM 
  start_table s
  LEFT join
  help_table hf ON s.Object = hf.Object AND hf.Group = 'fruits'
  LEFT join
  help_table hc ON s.Object = hc.Object AND hc.Group = 'cars'
GROUP BY Person
```

Adding a new column per group dynaically becomes trickier becuase SQL does not really support arbitrary column outputs

Comment: I made a fiddle to test your solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf0ae/2 . It doesn't quite get the desired result, because it doesn't SUM, but COUNT the different types of objects.

Comment: @A.Stam glad to help. The main bit transferring the subqueries to the JOIN so ypu can aggregate it

Answer (score 1):

Create two tables, fruits and cars:

```
SELECT
  s.Person,
  sum(fruits.count) as Fruits,
  sum(cars.count) AS Cars
FROM start_table s
    left join help_table fruits on s.[Object] = fruits.[Object] and fruits.[Group] = 'fruits'
    left join help_table cars on s.Object = cars.Object and cars.[Group] = 'cars'
GROUP BY s.Person
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sum and pivot as below:

```
 Select * from (
     Select [Person], [Group], sum([Count]) as sm from start_table s
        left join help_table h
        on s.[Object] = h.[Object]
        group by [Person], [Group]
    ) a
    pivot (sum(sm) for [Group] in ([fruits],[cars])) p
```

For dynamic list of [Group] you can query as below

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName([Group]) from help_table  for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Set @query = '   Select * from (
         Select [Person], [Group], [Count] from start_table s
            left join help_table h
            on s.[Object] = h.[Object]
        ) a
        pivot (sum([Count]) for [Group] in (' + @cols1 + ')) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Also you can remove aggregation in subquery as aggregation is handled in pivot itself. Updated that in dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get this with common table expression. Below query will give result in desired format. I have also created a sqlfiddle at [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc056/2). Sometime SqlFiddle doesn't load properly, incase try again on link. Please feel free to take a look.

```
SELECT
  Person,
  ISNULL(Cars, 0) Cars,
  ISNULL(Fruits, 0) Fruits
FROM (SELECT
  Person,
  [Group],
  SUM([Count]) AS TotalCount
FROM Userdata
JOIN ItemGroup
  ON ItemGroup.Item = Userdata.Item
GROUP BY Person,
         [Group]) x
PIVOT
(
SUM(TotalCount)
FOR [Group] IN ([fruits], [cars])
) pvt
```

Comment: This returns multiple rows per individual. Your result table does not match the desired outcome.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. You can find updated fiddle at : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc056/2